# reducing an array of steps to a smaller array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of steps, as an example an I'll use letters:

```
let steps=['f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'h', 'i' ]
```

and a merge function which takes two steps and return a merged step if it can merge them or null if it can't, as an example it will concat two consecutive letters:

```
function nextLetter(s){
    return s.replace(/([a-zA-Z])[^a-zA-Z]*$/, function(a) {
        var c= a.charCodeAt(0);
        if (c===90 || c===122) return null; else return String.fromCharCode(++c);
        }
    });
}

// merge('x', 'a') -> null , marge('x', 'y') -> 'xy'
function mergeSteps(s1, s2) {
   if (s2==nextLetter(s1)) return s1+s2; else return null;
}
```

I now need to write a `mergeStepsArray` function, this will receive an array of steps and return a new array by trying to merge as many consequent steps as possible, so that considering the steps array above:

`mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeSteps);` will return  `['f', 'bcd', 'x', 'hi' ]`

How can I write such a function efficiently ? I tried to use Array.reduce but I can't get it to work in this case.

NOTE: I need a `mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeSteps)` that is **general** and does not know the specifics of it's arguments. For example steps can be made of numbers and mergeSteps could `return s2==s1*2 ? s1*s2 : null`

Thanks

Comment: Could use clarification, should it merge recursively? IE `'bcd...'`? Or just a single iteration?

Comment: yes it should, I'll update my question, thx

Comment: question should make more sense now

Comment: That's the point...if it's not strings what are other possibilities? Higher level objective is vague. Question needs a more complete explanation

Comment: point is it can be anything, that's the whole point, I need a general algorithm, mergeSteps knows how to merge steps, that's all mergeStepsArray needs to know, what's vague ?

Comment: But your `mergeSteps()` is not recursive , you can't write a general function if that argument doesn't fulfill full merge.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you say or you don't understand the question

Comment: Take any of these answers and wrap them calling all their code `mergeSteps` and pass that into your new function along with steps array. Your version is not complete enough to do what you are asking

Comment: I just explained what you need to do. Your `mergeSteps` is not recusrisive and doesn't complete  a whole steps merge

Comment: What you are asking will not work then until you make your mergesteps function do the full array , not just 2 elements in the array

Comment: sorry you don't understand my question, pls read again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with:

```js
var steps = ['f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'h', 'i', 'z'];

function mergeStep(x, y) {
  if ((x.charCodeAt(x.length - 1) + 1) % 97 == y.charCodeAt(0) % 97) {
    return x + y;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

function mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeStep) {
  let mergedSteps = [];
  for (let i = 1, step = steps[0]; i <= steps.length; i++)
    step = steps[i] && mergeStep(step, steps[i]) || mergedSteps.push(step) && steps[i]
  return mergedSteps
}

alert(mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeStep))
```

Answer (score 1):

This work even if the steps are strings:

```js
let steps=['f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'xgoog', 'h', 'i', 'd' ];

// check if the first character of b is just next the last character of a
function valid(a, b) {
  return a.charCodeAt(a.length - 1) + 1 === b.charCodeAt(0);
}


let result = [];
// the first entry of steps as the current a
let current = steps[0];
for(var i = 1; i < steps.length; i++) {
  // if this step is valid add it to current to accumulate the result
  if(valid(current, steps[i]))
    current += steps[i];
  // if not then push the accumulated result into the array, and start another one from this step
  else {
    result.push(current);
    current = steps[i];
  }
}
// push the last one
result.push(current);


console.log(result);
```

**IN GENERAL:**

The logic should be like this:

```
// reduceArray should take three parameters: 
//  * arr: the array,
//  * check: the function responsible for the decision wether to merge or not (takes two parameters and check if they're mergeable)
//  * merge: the function that merges two elements (takes two parameters, merges them and return the result)
function reduceArray(arr, checkFn, mergeFn) {
    // check for errors
    if(!arr || !(arr instanceof Array) || arr.length == 0) return [];
    if(!checkFn || typeof checkFn != "function") return [];
    if(!mergeFn || typeof mergeFn != "function") return [];

    var result = [];

    // current should take the value of the first item in the array so ...
    var current = arr[0];
    // the loop starts at 1
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // always check if current is mergeable with arr[i]
        if(checkFn(current, arr[i])){
            // if so, store the merge result in current and re-check again for the next element
            current = mergeFn(current, arr[i]);
        }
        else {
            // if not store the result, and start another check-merge starting from this index (arr[i])
            result.push(current);
            current = arr[i];
        }
    }
    // don't forget to store the last element (merged or not)
    result.push(current)

    return result;
}


function myCheck(a, b) {
    /* check if a could be merged with b */
    /* must return true or false */
}

function myMerge(a, b) {
    /* merge a with b and return the result */
}

// and then call reduceArray like this:
var myArr = new Array();
// ...
var result = reduceArray(myArr, myCheck, myMerge);
// or like this
var result = reduceArray(myArr, function(a, b){
    /* return true or false depending on whether a and b are mergeable or not */
}, function(a, b){
    /* merge a and b and return the result */
})
```

**Another approach:**

I also added the check for the callback (to see if it is a valid callback).

```
// reduceArray should take three parameters: 
//  * arr: the array,
//  * mergeStepsFn: takes two parameter and return the result if they're mergeable, null othrwise
function reduceArray(arr, mergeStepsFn) {
    // check for errors
    if(!arr || !(arr instanceof Array) || arr.length == 0) return [];
    if(!mergeStepsFn || typeof mergeStepsFn != "function") return [];

    var result = [];

    var current = arr[0];
    for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        // get the result of merging current with the arr[i]
        var mergeResult = mergeStepsFn(current, arr[i]);
        // if merge was successful
        if(mergeResult !== null){ // should compare against null since we have no idea about the data types
            // if so, store the merge result in current
            current = mergeResult;
        }
        else {
            // if not store the accumulated result, and start another check-merge starting from this index (arr[i])
            result.push(current);
            current = arr[i];
        }
    }
    // don't forget to store the last element (merged or not)
    result.push(current)

    return result;
}


function myMergeStepsFunction(a, b) {
    /* if a is mergeable with b then return the merge result, if not return null */
}

// and then call reduceArray like this:
var myArr = new Array();
// ...
var result = reduceArray(myArr, myMergeStepsFunction);
// or like this
var result = reduceArray(myArr, function(a, b){
    /* if a is mergeable with b then return the merge result, if not return null */
});
```

Comment: I need a mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeSteps) that is general and does not know the specifics of it's arguments

Comment: @kofifus I updated my answer. Check the **IN GENERAL** section above!

Comment: can you write a general solution with the signature mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeSteps) as required in the question, there is no need for a separate 'check' function

Comment: @kofifus This is the best approach as a check function is needed. In your question you said that the merge should occur if a condition is true (if the characters are next to each other), you've even implemented that function. **it's more flexible that way**.

Comment: in the question mergeSteps does both - it returns null if merging fails

Comment: @kofifus I updated my answer to include your desired appraoch. see **Another approach** section!

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this

```
var steps = ['f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'h', 'i' ];

function checkStepSingle(x, y){
  if((x.charCodeAt(x.length-1)+1) % 97 == y.charCodeAt(0)%97){
    return x + y;
  }
  else{
    return null;
  }
}

function mergeArray(array, mergeSteps){
  var returnArray = array.slice();
  for(i = 0; i+1 < returnArray.length; i++){
    var step = mergeSteps(returnArray[i], returnArray[i+1]);
    if(step != null){
      returnArray[i] = step;
      returnArray.splice(i+1, 1);
      i = i-1;
    }
  }

  return returnArray;
}
console.log(mergeArray(steps, checkStepSingle))
console.log(steps)
```

But if you want to use also capital letters you have to change the number 97 to 65.

> Another approach
>   This way is from back to front. You just add elements if they can't be reduced with the next one. To be 100% sure you should add an if else statement in the beginning to be sure you don't run into a null array.

```
var steps = ['f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'h', 'i' ];

function checkStepSingle(x, y){
  if((x.charCodeAt(x.length-1)+1) % 97 == y.charCodeAt(0)%97){
    return x + y;
  }
  else{
    return null;
  }
}

function mergeArray(array, mergeSteps){
  var tmpArray = [];
  var tmp = array[0];
  for(i = 0; i+1 < array.length; i++){
    var step = mergeSteps(tmp, array[i+1]);
    if(step != null){
      tmp = step;
    }
    else{
      tmpArray.push(tmp);
      tmp = array[i+1];
    }
  }
  tmpArray.push(tmp);

  return tmpArray;
}
console.log(mergeArray(steps, checkStepSingle))
console.log(steps)
```

Comment: I need a mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeSteps) that is general and does not know the specifics of it's arguments

Comment: so then you can add another parameter to the mergeArray which is the function and use it instead of mergeSteps.

Comment: I don't understand your code, there's a checkStepSingle that is never called ? see my question - I need a mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeSteps) function

Comment: the mergeStepSingle is the function which will merge the data type you use in steps. 
And I changed the function name from the top. I did a mistake with the names not it should be more clear.

Comment: this is really good ! but it changes the original array passed to mergeArray, I am looking for a function returning a new result array

Comment: Just add a array in the function which is a copy of the passed array

Comment: this should be what you need.

Comment: yeah but I think this is now inefficient, I don't think there's a need to copy the array and splice it, see Ibrahim solution above

Comment: How about this solution? It starts with an empty Array.

Comment: interesting, but I'm not sure if going backwards is ok, you assume mergeStep(mergeStep(s1, s2),s3)==mergeStep(s1, mergeStep(s2,s3)) which is not a requirement I want

Comment: Then you have to choose and setup a mergeStep properly. Since I don't know what exactly is the data type you are working with I can just give you a good performing algorithm. Be more specific what you are talking about. The requirement `mergeStep(mergeStep(s1, s2), s3) == mergeStep(s1, mergeStep(s2, s3))` will be true for string type but you have to specify the mergeStep for this requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with reduce and split:

```js
let steps=['f', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'h', 'i' ];


function mergeSteps(s1, s2) {
   return s1.charCodeAt(0) - s2.charCodeAt(0) == 1 ? true : false;
}

var step1 = steps.reduce(function(acc, curr, ind, arr){
   if(ind > 0 && mergeSteps(curr, arr[ind - 1])){
      acc = acc + curr;
   }
   else {
      acc = acc + "-" +curr;
   }
 return acc;
}).split("-");

console.log(step1);
```

Comment: thanks ! I used strings only as an example, I am looking for a general mergeStepsArray(steps, mergeSteps) function that can then be applied in this case. Can you convert your solution to such ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the actual input set and output that you want to transform?

Comment: same input and output will do for testing, but I need mergeStepsArray logic to be implemented in terms of it's arguments (that is by calling mergeSteps) without knowing the type of the array elements etc

Comment: @kofifus Doesn't make any sense what you've just said. If they're number how would you merge them? If they are mixed types (strings, numbers, objects ...) how would you merge those too?

Comment: the point is, the mergeSteps function knows how to merge two steps, it doesn't matter how it does that, for example if steps are numbers it could multiply them ...

Comment: @kofifus - check the snippet above.  i have extracted out the mergeSteps function, this is where you can put your logic to merge the two steps.

Comment: thx, you are still doing string concats (acc = acc + "-" +curr) but I can't assume steps are strings except inside mergeSteps, pls see the question